# Fetch variable from a .txt

Tags: python

I am making a program that sends out emails for me, however I want to have presets for the emails that are sent out something like this

```
if language == "EN":
    message = """\
Subject: email subject

email body""
```

However I want to use multiple languages (presets) and if I make 30 if statements my code will look very cluttered, so I was wondering if its possible to put the **message**  variable in a .txt and make the program open the .txt and look for it in the txt.

edit: I want to add multiple variables into this txt so can I make python differentiate a variable labelled **english** from **spanish**

Comment: Well, if it's multiple (human) languages, perhaps have a look at Internationalization https://docs.python.org/3/library/i18n.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could save your templates in a JSON file, e.g.

```
{ 
    "en": {
        "Subject": "Email subject",
        "Body": "Email body"
    }
    "sp": {
         [...]
    }
}
```

If you then import that file as a dictionary `lang_dict`, you can retrieve the subject/body required using the syntax `lang_dict[language]['Subject']`, etc. This replaces the 30 `if` clauses you'd otherwise need.